# Insert Object in Array before other object in array with specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, insert, compare

I have one Array with objects. All objects habe one unique id. Now I want to insert a new Object before the object with the specific id. To do that I get this object:

```
{"topic":"add","payload":{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0},"row":-1,"socketid":"SSZY-1C3jiP8-NS2AAAB","_msgid":"a891f409.e30038"}
```

and now I need to find this object in this array with the id:

```
[{"woche":"Montag","status":0,"_children":[{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Dienstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":2,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Mittwoch","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":3,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Donnerstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":4,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Freitag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":5,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Samstag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":6,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Sonntag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":7,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]}]
```

and now I want to insert a new object bofore the object with the matching id.

How can I find the position in the array and how can I add this object?

```
{"id":`${++Id}`,"end":"","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}
```

At the end it should look like this:

```
[{"woche":"Montag","status":0,"_children":[{"id":"8","end":"","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0},{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Dienstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":2,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Mittwoch","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":3,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Donnerstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":4,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Freitag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":5,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Samstag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":6,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Sonntag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":7,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]}]
```

Comment: please add some linebreaks in the data structure. what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method to check for the index of the specific element.

Suppose this is your array:

```
let arr = [{"woche":"Montag","status":0,"_children":[{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Dienstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":2,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Mittwoch","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":3,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Donnerstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":4,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Freitag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":5,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Samstag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":6,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Sonntag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":7,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]}]
```

You need to search for the index of this object in the array:

```
let s = {"topic":"add","payload":{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0},"row":-1,"socketid":"SSZY-1C3jiP8-NS2AAAB","_msgid":"a891f409.e30038"}
```

You can use the following query to achieve this:

```
let index = -1
arr.filter((o) => {
    if(s.payload.id === o._children[0].id) {
        index = arr.indexOf(o)
    }
    return o
})
```

You can use `splice` method to add new object in the array at specific index.

```
arr.splice(index, 0, <value to enter in array>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` if you are writing for relatively modern web browsers or a node application:

```
const newItem; // I assume this is your object you want to insert
const fullArray; // I assume this is the full array

const result = fullArray.flatMap(
    item => item.id === "1" ? [newItem, item] : [item]
);
```

This is to my knowledge the most efficient way to get a new array `result` that is identical to `fullArray` except with `newItem` inserted every time before an item occurs in `fullArray` that fulfills the condition `item.id === "1"`.

A short explanation about `flatMap`: `.flatMap(x)` is an abbreviation for `.map(x).flat()` that is more efficient. The idea is that you have e.g. `[a, b, c, d]` and `.map()` it to `[[a], [b], [newItem, c], [d]]` which is then `.flat()`tened to `[a, b, newItem, c, d]`. Although `flatMap` does this without inefficiently going through both steps but instead does it in one go, so there is not much space for improvement efficiency wise.